# Nuxt.js with koajs How to use ctx.status or ctx.body in the asyncData method

Tags: nuxt.js, koa2

QUESTION: Nuxt.js with koajs How to use ctx.status or ctx.body in the asyncData method.

In the page component, this is my code:

```
export default {
    asyncData({app,redirect,query,req,next}) {
                req.ctx.res.status = 404;
        req.ctx.res.body = "message";
        req.ctx.res.end();
    }
}
```

But the console returned an error message: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent
To the client, how should I go about implementing them?